# Dúvida em Order By com LINQ para gerar relatório

Tags: asp.net-mvc, sql-server, linq-to-sql

Estou fazendo um relatório com o `iTextSharp` e ordeno pela data mas quando visualizo o relatório a empresa `Empresa2XYZ` aparece 2 vezes com a mesma data.

Segue o código com LINQ.

```cs
lista = context.TB_ContasPagar
                .Where(c => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.DataBaixa) >= dataInicial.Date && DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.DataBaixa) <= dataFinal.Date)
                .OrderBy(c => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.DataBaixa)).ToList();
                //.ThenBy(c => c.ID_EmpresaConta).ToList();
```

Tentei usar o `ThenBy` mas não resolveu o problema.

Segue imagem

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: conseguiu chegar a alguma conclusão?

Comment: Sugiro que melhore a descrição do problema, explicando o contexto. O relatório não deveria estar ordenado também por empresa?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

É bem difícil responder sem o contexto completo, mas vou tentar te guiar para como resolver esse problema.

A 1a coisa a fazer seria remover os `DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.DataBaixa)`. Parecem ser desnecessários. Caso não queira tem em conta o horário, a sua busca deveria ser pela data com os horários em 00:00 e 23:59:59. O mesmo para o `OrderBy`, a não ser que seja estritamente necessário que o seu retorno esteja ordenado pela data, ignorano o horário, e posteriormente por outra propriedade (como o nome da empresa), mas ainda assim poderia seguir uma abordagem diferente, se for o caso (não parece ser, dada a sua tentativa com `ThenBy(c => c.ID_EmpresaConta)`). Altere também a exibição do relatório para incluir o horário, para facilitar perceber o problema. Isso ainda não resolverá o seu problema, mas deve melhorar a sua query e facilitar a visualização dos dados.

Antes de tentar ver o problema no relatório, veja os valores presentes em `lista`. Imagino que existam 4 entradas para `Empresa2XYZ`. Para garantir que estes entradas estejam juntas no teu resultado fazer `.OrderBy(c => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(c.DataBaixa)).ThenBy(c => c.ID_EmpresaConta).ToList();` deveria de fato resolver o problema, mas sem ter todo o contexto do seu modelo de dados e dos dados, não consigo saber o motivo de não funcionar. Mais uma vez isso ainda não resolve o problema, mas o ajuda a tentar identificá-lo.

Por último, de modo a garantir que os resoltados estão agrupados, você poderia usar o `GroupBy` e agrupar por data (sem o horário, neste caso) e `ID` ou `nome` da empresa. Isso pode ser feito assim `.GroupBy(x => new { x.Column1, x.Column2 })`, onde `Column1` seria a sua data, sem hora, e `Column2` um identificador único para as empresas.